# php date format YYYY-MM-DD minus or add one week from now?

Tags: php

```
today 22-05-2011 so it should be 29-05-2011? ( plus 1 week ) 
or
today 22-05-2011 so it should be 15-05-2011? ( minus 1 week )
```

thanks for looking in.

Adam Ramadhan

Comment: Assume you meant "plus 1 week" on the first example.

Answer (score 74):

Use [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

```
echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime("+1 week")); //1 week in the future
echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime("-1 week")); //1 week ago
```

Comment: One should note that this is a very poor method of doing this, `strtotime` returns seconds since epoch, you can simply add or subtract one week in seconds to the time and avoid the slow call to `strtotime`. `$date = date('d-m-Y', time() + 604800);`

Comment: @HostFission your solution does not account for Daylight saving time changes, beware

Comment: @hexYeah indeed it does. `time()` returns a unix timestamp, which is seconds since January 1, 1970 12:00:00 AM UTC (The `U` being `Univeral`). It is then up to you to apply any timezone offsets, including taking DST into account. If this is not working for you be sure you have your timezone set correctly. `date` applies the local system timezone, if you wish to work with UTC you need to use `gmdate`. If you are working with [unix timestamps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) that have a timezone offset applied to them, then they are not unix timestamps.

Comment: @Geoffrey I was not referring to the answer but the comment below it. I felt the need to highlight because it had a +1 and I don't want people to see this it s a valid solution. If we are about to change the time in the following week the `+ 604800` does not cover that or even leap years

Comment: @hexYeah I don't think you're correct. The commenter is just adding a fixed number of seconds to the timestamp. DST is taken into consideration after the timestamp has been modified, it's got nothing to do with adding 604800 seconds to the timestamp.

Comment: If there is a DST change in the next week but you use `+604800` you would be off by +/- an hour, which would be wrong if you convert that time stamp to date (d-m-Y 23:00), even worst for a leap year.
`strtotime(+/- x weeks);` accounts for that. I've been there... +7*24*60*60 is not reliable

Comment: @hexYeah I am referring to the comment also. You are completely incorrect on this, a UTC unix timestamp is THE standard. DST varies from place to place, even for when it comes into effect, I live in a timezone with DST and have to deal with this also. A unix timestamp is a clean, unmolested scientific standard. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593692/convert-unix-timestamp-to-date-without-system-libs as to how to actually convert from a Unix timestamp to date correctly, taking leap years into account. You can also see the source in glibc to see how timezones are handled.

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time guys, I was sure I ran into this issue not too long ago. It must not have been exactly what I remember... I will still look it up :P but you make a point...

Answer (score 32):

You can use the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) class to do calendar calculations. For exaple, to add one week, you could use code like this:

```
$date = new DateTime('22-05-2011');
$date->modify('+1 week');
```

Comment: or $date->add(new DateInterval('P1W'));

Comment: One liner: `$date = (new DateTime('22-05-2011'))->modify('+1 week');`

Answer (score 17):

[strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) will handle this.

```
$pDate = strtotime('22-05-2011 + 1 week');
echo date('d-m-Y',$pDate);
```

---

Added:  This is if you want to start from a specific date.  If you just want 'today' +/- a week', mark JohnP's answer as correct.  : )

Answer (score 0):

In case If you dint want to hard code today's date you can use Carbon class methods of php.

```
Carbon::now()->subWeek(1);
Carbon::now()->addWeek(1);
```