# php get oldest record and add 1 week

Tags: php, datetime, time, increment

I'm looking at making an automated post once a week blog so I can create more postings and then have them go out once a week. I'm having some trouble getting the greatest time and adding 1 week to it.

My database I'm using "datetime".
So the string is in "2013-03-20 09:42:41".

I can get the value of greatest post `blog_date`, but how do I add 1 week to the string?

```
date('$blog_date', strtotime("+1 week"));
```

Thanks for your time ^^

ANSWER WORKS:

```
$blog_date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime("+1 week", strtotime($newest)));
```

Comment: same question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086389/php-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-minus-or-add-one-week-from-now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Datetime object to add a week easily

http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php

```
$date = new DateTime('2013-03-20 09:42:41');
$date->modify('+1 week');
```

Comment: awesome thanks I also figured out $blog_date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime("+4 days", strtotime($newest)));

Comment: @Tuim what's the output you get by your above code?

Comment: @SumitBijvani `2013-03-27 09:42:41` you can see with `echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
$blog_date = "2013-03-20 09:42:41";
$date2 = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($blog_date)) . "+1 week");
echo date('Y-m-d', $date2);
```

**Output**

```
2013-03-27
```