# Does modulus use floating point behind the scenes?

Tags: c++

In C++ does a modulus use any floating point math behind the scenes?

```
int x = 1234;
int y = 5678;
int z = y % x;  // any floating point used underneath to calculate the integer result?
```

As background, I was thinking about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593692/convert-unix-timestamp-to-date-without-system-libs) where he said he couldn't use any floating point without FP emulation. Then I realized that I wasn't sure if the modulus operator used any sort of floating point assembly operations. My guess is it does not, but I would like to be sure.

Comment: The result is simply the remainder after integer division...

Comment: _'Does modulus use floating point behind the scenes?'_ Simply: NO!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No<sup>1</sup>. Refer to some *implementations* of such an operator.

- [Assembly Language - How to Do Modulo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021772/assembly-language-how-to-do-modulo) - "[In x86] the DIV instruction [..] gives both the quotient and remainder"
- [Assembly mod algorithm on processor with no division operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938038/assembly-mod-algorithm-on-processor-with-no-division-operator)

---

<sup>1</sup> An *implementation* can do whatever it wants insofar as the observed behavior is within the specification. However, I don't know of any implementation which would choose to use floating point operations, nor can I think of a general justification for doing so.

Answer (score 2):

No it does not use the floating point arithmetic. The result can be obtained very simply

```
z = y - ( y/x ) * x;
```

Early computers sometimes have no floating point coprocessor. So such operations are performed by using machine commands that operate with integer numbers.

Answer (score 1):

It's up to the implementation how "C++" calculates the modulus "behind the scenes"

Comment: True, but misleading. Do you know of even one example architecture where the answer is 'yes'?