# PHP - Add one week to a user defined date

Tags: php, html

There's more than likely going to be a duplicate for this question, but I'm struggling to find a precise answer for my problem.

The user enters a starting date for a client's rent (on a form on a previous page), then it needs to generate the next date (one week later) that the client is required to pay. For example:

```
$start_date = $_POST['start_date'];  
$date_to_pay = ???
```

Lets say the user enters in 2015/03/02:

```
$start_date = "2015/03/02";
```

I then want the date to pay to be equal to a week later (2015/03/09):

```
$date_to_pay = "2015/03/09";
```

How would one go around doing this? Many thanks.

Comment: Yes! There are many, many duplicates: `$_POST['start_date'] = '2015/03/02';
$date = new DateTime($_POST['start_date']);
$date->add(new DateInterval('P1W'));
echo $date->format('Y/m/d');`

Comment: create date time from user input then add a week on it. For code see @MarkBaker 's comment

Comment: check this link : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086389/php-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-minus-or-add-one-week-from-now

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can try this

```
$start_date = "2015/03/02";  
$date = strtotime($start_date);
$date = strtotime("+7 day", $date);
echo date('Y/m/d', $date);
```

Comment: Sidenote: + 7 days is nice, but you could also just do + 1 week, just personnal preference..

Comment: One should note that this is a very poor method of doing this, `strtotime` returns seconds since epoch, you can simply add one week in seconds to the time and avoid the extra slow call to `strtotime`. `$date = strtotime($start_date) + 604800;`

Answer (score 15):

Please try the following:

```
date('d.m.Y', strtotime('+1 week', strtotime($start_date)));
```

Comment: So would I make $date_to_pay = date('d.m.Y', strtotime('+1 week', $start_date));??

Comment: Exactly, set as per your format Y/m/d.

Comment: I'm just trying it again cos for some reason my $date_to_pay came out as 1970/01/07 lol

Comment: @bob Yeah I don't know why but for some reason it outputs the $date_to_pay as 1970/01/07???

Comment: @Jack, `$start_date` is meant to be a unix timestamp, [see manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#refsect1-function.strtotime-description)

Answer (score 10):

Object Oriented Style using [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) classes:

```
$start_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d', $_POST['start_date']);

$one_week = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 week');

$start_date->add($one_week);

$date_to_pay = $start_date->format('Y/m/d');
```

Or for those who like to have it all in one go:

```
$date_to_pay = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d',$_POST['start_date'])
                       ->add(DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 week'))
                       ->format('Y/m/d');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$start_date = "2015/03/02";  
$new_date= date("Y/m/d", strtotime("$start_date +1 week"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
$startdate = $_POST['start_date'];
$date_to_pay = date('Y/m/d',strtotime('+1 week',$startdate));
```