# Adding days/weeks to formatted date

Tags: php

I have a date formatted like this: Ymd

I can't seem to find a way to be able to add a number of weeks to this date, I have tried the following:

```
$quote_start_date = $job['quote_authorised'];

$newdate = date($quote_start_date, strtotime('+5 weeks'));
```

However the new date is the same, what is the easiest way to add weeks to a date formatted like this?

Comment: what is the output of `$quote_start_date`? please show us.

Comment: Can you write down your input and exact desired output?

Comment: check out http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php

Comment: The output of quote_start_date, is a date, formatted like this: Ymd, so for example 20170618

Comment: @Aaranihlus Not sure why there is no dash(-) or forward slash (/) there when you are passing. Any particular reason may be.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Add one week to a user defined date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28807774/php-add-one-week-to-a-user-defined-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2nd parameter to `date` takes seconds since epoch. Just add 5 weeks in seconds to the time, ie:

```
$newdate = date($format, strtotime($quote_start_date) + (5 * 7 * 24 * 60 * 60));
```

Or just use the constant value "3024000"

```
$newdate = date($format, strtotime($quote_start_date) + 3024000);
```

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter of `date` expects a format for your outputted date string. I think you're looking for the following:

```
$quote_start_date = $job['quote_authorised'];
$newdate = date("Ymd", strtotime('+5 weeks', strtotime($quote_start_date)));
```

The more efficient approach would be to use a fixed value for the number of seconds in a week and not rely on PHP parsing an additional `strtotime` function:

```
$quote_start_date = $job['quote_authorised'];
$newdate = date("Ymd", strtotime($quote_start_date) + 3024000);
```

Comment: This is extremely ineffecient, you are asking PHP to parse '+5 weeks' which will just return a constant value of `3024000`. Just add 3024000 to the first `strtotime` call.

Answer (score 0):

Its a demo :

```
 $date = new Date();
 $nextDate = new Date($date.setTime( $date.getTime() + 1 * 86400000 ));
 // here 1 is number of day .
```

Comment: "add weeks to a date", not add weeks to the current time.