# how to find the last week from today's date?

Tags: php, date

Can anyone help me how to find last week starting date or ending date using currentdate

Suppose i am having today date is :-

```
enter code here
date('y-m-d') = 2017-01-31 today is Tuesday
```

So i want last week starting date and ending date output like

```
enter code here

last Week starting date:- 2017-01-23
last week ending date :- 2017-01-29
```

Can anyone hlp me how to do that

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086389/php-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-minus-or-add-one-week-from-now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php date format YYYY-MM-DD minus or add one week from now?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086389/php-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-minus-or-add-one-week-from-now)

Comment: i want to find with today's date not statically

Comment: please read my question carefully after selecting duplicate

Comment: did you tried the marked question.. what did you tried??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first get the week number than get previous week and get its date.

```
   $ddate = "2017-1-31";
$date = new DateTime($ddate);
$week = $date->format("W");
$year = $date->format("o");
var_dump($week);
function etStartAndEndDate($week, $year) {
  $dto = new DateTime();
  $dto->setISODate($year, $week);
  $ret['week_start'] = $dto->format('Y-m-d');
  $dto->modify('+6 days');
  $ret['week_end'] = $dto->format('Y-m-d');
  return $ret;
}
  $day=etStartAndEndDate($week-1,$year);
var_dump($day)
```

Comment: thank you exactly i need thank you finally you understand my problem once again thank you

Comment: one minute i need to improve

Comment: ok one thing more if want to get the next week how can i do that i am waiting for your reply

Comment: for next week  $day=etStartAndEndDate($week-1,$year);

Comment: @krishnpatel it gives me current week when i put -1

Comment: @krishnpatel when i remove -1 it give me fine result

Comment: @kunal my ans has some mistake I have change it now use this one if you want previous one use -1 and if you want to next use +1, if you have any problems let me know

Comment: @kunal for which date ?

Comment: i want to add one week in curent week like today is 2017-01-31 i want output like starting on 6feb and end on 12th feb

Comment: than use this bro  for next week $day=etStartAndEndDate($week+1,$year); for last week make $week-1

Comment: Don't use `Y` format for year, when working with ISO weeks. Use `o` format for year. Based on that, your answer will not work for example `2014-12-31`...

Comment: @Glavić I have test this date and get perfect output for both last and nex week dates

Comment: @krishnpatel: can you support that statement with a link? [Here is my](https://eval.in/727518).

Comment: @Glavić  I accept this mistake. thank you very much. I have change my answer.

Comment: @krishnpatel: np, I just hope you understand the difference and will use it correctly in the future :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily using [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) functions this way:

```
    echo "today is: ".date("m/d/Y", strtotime("today"))."<br/>";
echo "last Week starting date: ".date("m/d/Y", strtotime("last week monday"))."<br/>";
echo "last Week ending date: ".date("m/d/Y", strtotime("last week sunday"));
```

Comment: thank you for reply if i want to get the second week of this month how can i get

Comment: `strtotime("second monday of $month $year")`. check this [demo](https://eval.in/727348)

Comment: well, you can always use strtotime doing something like this: `date('d', strtotime('second mon of january 2017'))`;

Answer (score 1):

I have check in example.. please try this can help you.

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$firstDayOfLastWeek = mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),date("d")-date("w")-6);
$lastDayOfLastWeek = mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),date("d")-date("w")-0);
echo("Last week began on: ".date("d.m.Y",$firstDayOfLastWeek));
echo("<br>");
echo("Last week ended on: ".date("d.m.Y",$lastDayOfLastWeek));
```